# When using an enum in a class would it be public and why?

Tags: c++, enums, private, public

I am using an enum for a class I am working on and I am using Google to look for examples to make sure I am using the enum correctly.  I went to several sites including the MSDN site and enums are listed under public instead of private.  I always thought that data members were private.  Am I off base and if so why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These enums are probably used in the class interface, right? Otherwise, it would indeed be cleaner to keep them `private`

Answer (score 18):

An enum is a type, not a data member. You should make it public if users of the class need to know about it; otherwise, make it private. A typical situation where users need to know about it is when it's used as the type of an argument to a public member function.

Answer (score 4):

Enums are not data members, they are constants/types. If you do not make them public, then other classes cannot interact with the class defining `enum` using enumeration names:

```
class A {
  public:
    void func(enumtype e) { if (e == e1) dostuff(); }
  private:
    typedef enum {e1, e2} enumtype;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.func(e1); // error: enumtype is private, e1 is not visible here
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Public `enum` data are heavily used in **template metaprogramming** (see [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html))

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

int main()
{
    auto const f10 = Factorial<10>::value; // done at compile-time
    std::cout << f10 << "\n";              // prints 3628800

    return 0;
}
```

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YpXlO). The reason that `enum` is used publicly here, is that the struct is a simply vehicle for transporting the intermediate computations to the top-level caller, and there is no encapsulation needed. It's a crude form of compile-time function evaluation, where the `struct` acts as the function scope and the `enum` as the return value.